# React Context values isnt being passed correctly, for private routes and session management

Tags: reactjs, routes, amazon-cognito, react-context

im trying to implement cognito login and session in my react app, and im facing an issue where the value determining if the user is logged in or not isnt passed correctly to the private routes file which is supposed to block and redirect the users accordingly.

here is account where all the functions that handle the user are defined, authenticate runs on form submit of the login screen.  (they work with cognito):

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import { CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
import Pool from "./UserPool";

const AccountContext = createContext();

const Account = (props) => {
  const getSession = async () => {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const user = Pool.getCurrentUser();
      if (user) {
        user.getSession((err, session) => {
          if (err) {
            reject();
          } else {
            resolve(session);
          }
        });
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  };
  const authenticate = async (Username, Password) => {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const user = new CognitoUser({
        Username,
        Pool,
      });

      const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
        Username,
        Password,
      });

      user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
        onSuccess: (data) => {
          const userData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
          const userIdentity = userData.idToken.payload["custom:tableau"];
          console.log("onSuccess: ", userIdentity);
          resolve(data);
          
        },
        onFailure: (err) => {
          console.log("onFailure: " + err);
          reject(err);
        },
        newPasswordRequired: (data) => {
          console.log("newPasswordRequired: " + JSON.stringify(data));
          const userData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
          const userIdentity = userData["custom:tableau"];
          console.log("userIdentity-passwordRequired: ", userIdentity);
          resolve(data);
        },
      });
    });
  };

 

  const logout = () => {
    const user = Pool.getCurrentUser();
    if(user){
      user.signOut();
    }
  };





  return (
    <AccountContext.Provider value={{  getSession, logout, authenticate }}>
      {props.children}
    </AccountContext.Provider>
  );
};
export { Account, AccountContext };
```

here is the Status.js where the monitoring of the login status happends

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AccountContext } from "./Account";

export const StatusContext = createContext();

export const StatusProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
  const { getSession } = useContext(AccountContext);

  useEffect(() => { 
    getSession().then((session) => {
      console.log("Session: ", session);
       setStatus(true);
      console.log("status: ",status)
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Updated status: ", status); // This will show the updated value
  }, [status]);

  return (
    <StatusContext.Provider value={{ status }}>
      {children}
    </StatusContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default StatusProvider;
```

this is PrivateRoutes.js:

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { StatusContext } from "../LoginScreen/Status";

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
    const  {status}  = useContext(StatusContext);
    console.log(status);

    return status ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/*" replace />;
};

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

and this is how index.js looks (i know its kind of messy im just trying to make this work ASAP):

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import "./i18n";

import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import "./App.css";
import LoginScreen from "./routes/LoginScreen/LoginScreen";

import { NavbarProvider } from "./NavbarContext";
import Elections from "./routes/something/something";
import Whatif from "./routes/something1/something2";
import { Account } from "./routes/LoginScreen/Account";
import StatusProvider from "../src/routes/LoginScreen/Status";
import PrivateRoutes from "./routes/Utils/PrivateRoutes";
import NotLogged from "./routes/Utils/NotLoggedIn";
import Distance1 from "./routes/something/something";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
      <Account>
        <StatusProvider>
          <NavbarProvider>
            <LoginScreen />
          </NavbarProvider>
        </StatusProvider>
      </Account>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "/*",
    element: (
      <Account>
      <StatusProvider>
        <NavbarProvider>
          <NotLogged />
        </NavbarProvider>
        </StatusProvider>
      </Account>
    ),
  },
  {
    element: (
      <Account>
      <StatusProvider>
        <NavbarProvider>
          <Navbar />
        </NavbarProvider>
        <PrivateRoutes />
        </StatusProvider>
      </Account>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: "dashboard1",
        element: <something />,
      },
      {
        path: "dashboard2",
        element: <something />,
      },
      {
        path: "dashboard3",
        element: <something />,
      },
    ],
  },
];

// Create a router
const router = createBrowserRouter(routes);

// Create a top-level component that wraps the router with context providers
function App() {
  return (
    <Account>
      <StatusProvider>
        <NavbarProvider>
          <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </NavbarProvider>
      </StatusProvider>
    </Account>
  );
}

// Render the app using createRoot
createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

the console logs are as follows:

initialy
**updated status: false**
when trying to access a protected route:
**updated status: false**
after correct credentials login:
**updated status: true**  but the page rendering is the not logged in page!!! this is where the problem resides since if the status is true it should render the main page (outlet).

Thanks a lot in advance!